# date time with nls language in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, date, select

need to convert the oracle format sql to mysql.

```
to_date(25-JAN-2020,'DD-MON-YYYY','nls_date_language = FRENCH').
```

in mysql, we can alter session to change the nls_date_language,  but instead of the changing alter session can we use like above oracle in mysql with datetime alone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is worth than you think.

In MySQL, the equivalent for Oracle's `to_date()` is `str_to_date()`, and `nls_date_language` would correspond to system variable [`lc_time_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_time_names).

*However*, as [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html) (emphasis is mine):

> This variable affects the output from the `DATE_FORMAT()`, `DAYNAME()`, and `MONTHNAME()` functions.
>
> `lc_time_names` **does not affect the `STR_TO_DATE()`** or `GET_FORMAT()` function.

So there is no way that you can actually parse a date in `dd-mon-yyyy` format where `mon` is a non-English month using only built-in functions and system variables.

The only solution I can think of is manually translating the date abbreviation before parsing, with a a lot of nested `REPLACE()`s or with a `CASE` expression... The fact that some of the month names do match between French and English simplifies the task a little:

```
select str_to_date(
    case 
        when mystr like '%FEV%' then replace(mystr, 'FEV', 'FEB')
        when mystr like '%AVR%' then replace(mystr, 'AVR', 'APR'),
        when mystr like '%MAI%' then replace(mystr, 'MAI', 'MAY')
        when mystr like '%JUI%' then replace(mystr, 'JUI', 'JUL'),
        when mystr like '%AOU%' then replace(mystr, 'AOU', 'AUG')
    end,
    '%d-%b-%Y'
) mydate
from ...
```